# How to get x number of an integer in python

Tags: python, math, integer

For example my number is **4857604**

In **python**, I just need only first 3 of this integer, it means I need this number : **485**

How I should do that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: int(4857604/10000)

Comment: You can get the three left-most digits of an integer x by `str(x)[:3]`

Comment: @but-why But why not just use floor division?

Comment: @superbrain I did not give a serious answer as the question was not well defined. I didn't think it would cause such trouble. The other guy as you see, casts to string and then takes the first 3 chars, but forgot he should do ```int(str(x)[:3])``` @DarrylG I hope I will come up with a slower solution.

Comment: @but-why It's unclear whether the OP needs it as int. I mean, they say "first 3 of this integer", which doesn't make sense, as an integer doesn't have "first 3". So maybe they don't even have an int to begin with but a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str(4857604)[:3]
```

or:

```
int(4857604/10000)
```

Time compare:

```
timeit("""str(4857604)[:3]""")
0.1730724999999893
timeit("""int(4857604/10000)""")
0.0691777999999772
timeit("""4857604//10000""")
0.006821999999999662
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of the number you could do this:

```
4857604//10000
```

The floor division removes the numbers after the comma

Answer (score 0):

```
def show_x_digits(num, x):
    return num / (10 ** x)


print(int(show_x_digits(4857604, 3)))
```

Just divide to 10^x and cast to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have integer back, instead of string you can do:

**1) Step by step**

```
x = 4857604
x = str(x)
x = x[:3]
x = int(x)
```

*...or much simplier*

**2)**

```
x =  int(str(x)[:3])
```

If you know exact size of number which you'll decrease you could also use integer division operator **//**

```
4857604 // 100000 = 485
```

Answer (score -1):

```
y = str(x)
x1 = int(y[0])
x2 = int(y[1])
x3 = int(y[2])
result = 100 * x1 + 10 * x2 + x3
```

EDIT:

```
result = int('{}{}{}'.format(x1, x2, x3))
```

Comment: Your answer is too complicated, not maintainable, could be done in many better ways. (BTW I haven't downvoted)